# Web Forms for Marketers MVC error

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

We have installed the WFFM (version 2.5 rev 141014)  module on a Sitecore 7.5 (rev 141003) instance, using MVC. The package install goes fine and we can see all the proper items in the tree and the functionality in Content/Page Editor works, but when we add a form to a page we get this error:

```
Exception Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Controllers.FormController, 

Sitecore.Forms.Mvc: Could not create a controller instance from type name: 'Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Controllers.FormController, Sitecore.Forms.Mvc'

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.CreateControllerUsingReflection()
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.GetController()
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ControllerRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
```

We've checked all the DLLs and view files and they all appear to match other instances we have and also match the files that are in the WFFM install package. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you might be missing a DLL during deployment, but really I don't think you've provided enough information to resolve the issue.

Comment: Let me know what other types of information do you need and I'll update the question.

Comment: How about how you are deploying for starters.

Comment: @Scott version of WFFM might be helpful as well.

Comment: I've added version/revision information to the question. Jonathan, as far as deployment, we're just installing the WFFM package, doing a full site publish, creating a sample form and trying to add it to a page. We've confirmed that the files that are in the package are on the file system, including all DLLs. We've refreshed our DB and installed the package several times and we get the same error each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We figured out the issue. We're using [this error handling technique](http://www.hhogdev.com/blog/2015/june/mvc-rendering-exception-handler.aspx) to wrap the execution of our components. WFFM uses a custom ControllerRenderer (FormControllerRenderer). Of course, our custom exception handling doesn't know about this custom class. We've update our code to check for the form renderer and return the correct type, which solved the issue.

[This post](http://cardinalcore.co.uk/2014/10/08/web-form-for-marketers-mvc-hijacked-my-pipeline/) helped me realize the issue.